# How to dynamically change the PayPal address in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I am trying to change the PayPal address that Woocommerce uses, depending on what page they are on. I only have 5 products at the moment, and all 5 need to use a different PayPal address.

I found this hook that can change the Paypal address, although not too sure how to add it in exactly (code is 3 years old apparently).

```
$paypal_args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', $paypal_args );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args' , 'custom_override_paypal_email' );

function custom_override_paypal_email( $paypal_args ) {
    $paypal_args['business'] = 'paypalemail@domain.com';
    print_r( $paypal_args['business'] );
    return $paypal_args;
}
```

How can I use this hook to change the Paypal address depending on which page/product the user is on?

Comment: and what if all of the products are in cart?

Comment: @Reigel - I direct the user straight to checkout instead of the cart

Comment: but even though you directed them to checkout, they can still visit another product and add it to cart...

Comment: @Reigel - Very true. I'll need to clear the cart each time a new product is added then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've checked and found out that `woocommerce_paypal_args` has two arguments, the settings and the order. So based on the order, we can check what product it has and use the appropriate email.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args' , 'custom_override_paypal_email', 10, 2 );

function custom_override_paypal_email( $paypal_args, $order ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
       switch( $item['product_id'] ) {
           case 561:
             $paypal_args['business'] = 'paypalemail1@domain.com';
             break;
           case 562:
             $paypal_args['business'] = 'paypalemail2@domain.com';
             break;
       }
    }

    return $paypal_args;
}
```

please take note that you have to make sure that there can only be one item on the cart. If there are more than 1 product in the cart, this will use the last found product in the `foreach` loop. The code above is just for guidance, please change accordingly.

Comment: Looks very good. Would i just place that in my Wordpress `functions.php` file?

Comment: Just tested it with sandbox accounts and works perfectly. Will award the bounty in 21 hours. Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of a hook that sends the confirmation email to that particular email address to?

Comment: @Reigel  In `switch( $item['prouct_id'] ) {` isn't `switch( $item['product_id'] ) {`? :)

Comment: Is this method safe to use?