# Filtering PayPal 'Custom' Field Sent By Woocommerce Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I need to manipulate the data Woocommerce sends to PayPal in the 'Custom' Field. When Woocommerce creates the order and sends the data this can be found in

```
$order['custom']
```

This string is json encoded and I've got a filter I'm trying to use but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I've got:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_paypal_args', 'send_custom_paypal_data');
function send_custom_paypal_data($order) {
    error_log(print_r($order['custom'], true)); //log variable
    $order['custom'] = wp_json_encode(
        array(
            'field1' => 'some value',
            'field2' => 'more values'
        )
    );
    error_log(print_r($order['custom'], true)); //log value after updating variable
    return $order;
}
```

The first time I dump the `$order['custom']` variable to the error_log I get the expected value from the Woocommerce order. But the 2nd time around, it's the same value, nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you share what is the output of first error_log and second error_log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$order` is the second parameter and not the first.

Also you should set the hook **priority** and number of **parameters**.

The **`woocommerce_paypal_args`** hook is defined in: `/woocommerce/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-request.php`.

Try with this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', 'send_custom_paypal_data', 10, 2 );
function send_custom_paypal_data( $args, $order ) {

    error_log( print_r( $args['custom'], true) ); //log variable

    $args['custom'] = wp_json_encode(
        array(
            'field1' => 'some value',
            'field2' => 'more values'
        )
    );
    
    error_log( print_r( $args['custom'], true) ); //log value after updating variable

    return $args;

}
```

*The code has been tested and works for me. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

**LOG REPORT**

The first log returns:

```
[10-Apr-2021 08:54:04 UTC] {"order_id":145,"order_key":"wc_order_8FSKEF2hg2UVu"}
```

and the second:

```
[10-Apr-2021 08:54:04 UTC] {"field1":"some value","field2":"more values"}
```

It works well for me.

**IF IT WAS NOT TO WORK**

- You're using the PayPal gateway included in the WooCommerce plugin, right?
- Have you checked if there are any other functions overriding yours? Or that they have a higher priority?
- Have you installed another PayPal plugin? In this case, deactivate it.

**RELATED ANSWERS** *(using the `woocommerce_paypal_args` hook)*

- [How to dynamically change the PayPal address in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027159/how-to-dynamically-change-the-paypal-address-in-woocommerce)
- [Adding custom args to Paypal Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424283/adding-custom-args-to-paypal-woocommerce)
- [Sending only order number instead of item names to PayPal in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221852/sending-only-order-number-instead-of-item-names-to-paypal-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Thanks, will test and see if it works. The $order variable had the array of data I wanted, i still don't understand why it wouldn't update the value of that array field locally within the function

Comment: You are using `$order` as an array and not as an order object, **so correctly**. I advised you to add all the arguments to the function because, as you have seen, there really is a second `$order` parameter which is the order object. To avoid confusion it would be better to rename the `$order` variable if this is used to access PayPal order arguments and not the order object.

Comment: It might also be useful to show the logs in your file (first and second) as recommended by @gautamgolakiya. Post them in your question.