# Editing PayPal 'Custom' Field Data Sent By Woocommerce Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

My question related to this slightly [Filtering PayPal 'Custom' Field Sent By Woocommerce Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030698/filtering-paypal-custom-field-sent-by-woocommerce-order)

```
"Request Body":{
   "transmission_id":"************-5c84-11ee-b8fb-************",
   "transmission_time":"2023-09-26T15:51:42Z",
   "cert_url":"https:\/\/api.paypal.com\/v1\/notifications\/certs\/CERT-************-************-************",
   "auth_algo":"SHA256withRSA",
   "transmission_sig":"************+OV0Cc7kkqyYNgZhDIUYNF5KGa\/************\/+k0Qn7mJU1FoeQk1TmHjQCtNZAYrKNmpFE6n2WmXeCwqB1PAzh\/e3VHQNS0EoIUv4NkHmK0bMJgIKfCohGsn0FBu4irGmF+ZWo1a+WAB4JBm3SdZPCCQzW7QY6OPKbxvvDsMnRCrtXtkCC2qnatJWf3RcioK\/wh2EKq66tlXf0iDq01\/Eh2u3eBxF+n4vccI2eDnZmFFjG7clVRVbLCA==",
   "webhook_id":"************",
   "webhook_event":{
      "id":"************-************-************",
      "event_version":"1.0",
      "create_time":"2023-09-26T15:51:39.554Z",
      "resource_type":"capture",
      "resource_version":"2.0",
      "event_type":"PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED",
      "summary":"Payment completed for $ 15.0 USD",
      "resource":{
         "id":"************",
         "amount":{
            "currency_code":"USD",
            "value":"15.00"
         },
         "final_capture":true,
         "seller_protection":{
            "status":"ELIGIBLE",
            "dispute_categories":[
               "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
               "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
            ]
         },
         "seller_receivable_breakdown":{
            "gross_amount":{
               "currency_code":"USD",
               "value":"15.00"
            },
            "paypal_fee":{
               "currency_code":"USD",
               "value":"1.16"
            },
            "net_amount":{
               "currency_code":"USD",
               "value":"13.84"
            }
         },
         "invoice_id":"cfbaf-6970",
         "custom_id":"6970",
         "status":"COMPLETED",
         "supplementary_data":{
            "related_ids":{
               "order_id":"************"
            }
         },
         "payee":{
            "email_address":"************@gmail.com",
            "merchant_id":"************"
         },
         "create_time":"2023-09-26T15:51:34Z",
         "update_time":"2023-09-26T15:51:39Z",
         "links":[
            {
               "href":"https:\/\/api.paypal.com\/v2\/payments\/captures\/************",
               "rel":"self",
               "method":"GET"
            },
            {
               "href":"https:\/\/api.paypal.com\/v2\/payments\/captures\/************\/refund",
               "rel":"refund",
               "method":"POST"
            },
            {
               "href":"https:\/\/api.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/************",
               "rel":"up",
               "method":"GET"
            }
         ]
      },
      "links":[
         {
            "href":"https:\/\/api.paypal.com\/v1\/notifications\/webhooks-events\/WH-************-************",
            "rel":"self",
            "method":"GET"
         },
         {
            "href":"https:\/\/api.paypal.com\/v1\/notifications\/webhooks-events\/WH-************-************\/resend",
            "rel":"resend",
            "method":"POST"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I need change value of `custom_id`

and here is how I edited `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-request.php` file function - but its not working - its looks like response attached

```
protected function get_transaction_args( $order ) {
        return array_merge(
            array(
                'cmd'           => '_cart',
                'business'      => $this->gateway->get_option( 'email' ),
                'no_note'       => 1,
                'currency_code' => get_woocommerce_currency(),
                'charset'       => 'utf-8',
                'rm'            => is_ssl() ? 2 : 1,
                'upload'        => 1,
                'return'        => esc_url_raw( add_query_arg( 'utm_nooverride', '1', $this->gateway->get_return_url( $order ) ) ),
                'cancel_return' => esc_url_raw( $order->get_cancel_order_url_raw() ),
                'image_url'     => esc_url_raw( $this->gateway->get_option( 'image_url' ) ),
                'paymentaction' => $this->gateway->get_option( 'paymentaction' ),
                'invoice'       => $this->limit_length( $this->gateway->get_option( 'invoice_prefix' ) . $order->get_order_number(), 127 ),
                'custom_id'        => wp_json_encode(
                    array(
                        'hh_vendor' => 'myvalue',
                        'order_id'  => $order->get_id(),
                        'order_key' => $order->get_order_key(),
                    )
                ), 
                'custom'        => wp_json_encode(
                    array(
                        'hh_vendor' => 'myvalue',
                        'order_id'  => $order->get_id(),
                        'order_key' => $order->get_order_key(),
                    )
                ), 
                'notify_url'    => $this->limit_length( $this->notify_url, 255 ),
                'first_name'    => $this->limit_length( $order->get_billing_first_name(), 32 ),
                'last_name'     => $this->limit_length( $order->get_billing_last_name(), 64 ),
                'address1'      => $this->limit_length( $order->get_billing_address_1(), 100 ),
                'address2'      => $this->limit_length( $order->get_billing_address_2(), 100 ),
                'city'          => $this->limit_length( $order->get_billing_city(), 40 ),
                'state'         => $this->get_paypal_state( $order->get_billing_country(), $order->get_billing_state() ),
                'zip'           => $this->limit_length( wc_format_postcode( $order->get_billing_postcode(), $order->get_billing_country() ), 32 ),
                'country'       => $this->limit_length( $order->get_billing_country(), 2 ),
                'email'         => $this->limit_length( $order->get_billing_email() ),
            ),
            $this->get_phone_number_args( $order ),
            $this->get_shipping_args( $order )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Directly editing a plugin file is a bad idea to begin with - the next update of that plugin, would undo all your modifications again. You should check if there is any hook available to manipulate this data set from outside of the plugin.

Comment: I editing this template for testing now and its do not send info that i add ( hook also do not sending my info

Comment: The [original method](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-gateways-paypal-includes-class-wc-gateway-paypal-request.html#source-view.118) does not appear to even be setting any `custom_id` entry explicitly, but you appear to be getting one in your result - so the only explanation I currently see, is that `$this->get_shipping_args( $order )` probably returns an array that contains `'custom_id' => '6970'`, and since `array_merge` will overwrite existing entries in case of string keys, you end up with that result.

Comment: Try and put an array `['custom_id' => ...]` _after_ that `$this->get_shipping_args( $order )` line - so that `array_merge` will overwrite the `custom_id` entry with your value again.

Comment: But you should _really_ implement this properly via the appropriate hook, like shown in that other question you referred to.